# Is there a way to access my OpenStack instance without floating IP?

Tags: ssh, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-keystone

It seems theoretically possible for me to ssh to my instance in OpenStack through credentials and instance id/network IP(Not floating IP) etc.
Is it possible, am I missing something? Is it simply a feature not yet supported?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to reach the VM with the local IP from dhcp namespace, which is usually in the network node or the node holding that role.

You need to get the network uuid

Something like:

```
ip netns => TO list them
ip netns exec qdhcp-<UUID> ping <VM IP>
ip netns exec qdhcp-<UUID> ssh <VM IP>
```